# How we can import a python file stored in memory using memfs

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have config.py file

```
def main():
        dataToReturn = {
    "url":"testurl"
               }
```

I have a python file myfile.py

```
from context import config
def main():
       testfunResp = config.main()
       logger.log("log in apistack")
       logger.log(testfunResp)
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    main();
```

and i am executing that file in node js using

```
let script_content = Reading file content of (myfile.py)

let scriptExecution = spawn('python', ['-c', script_content], inputParams, req.headerDetails]);
```

Here in that file i have import statement

```
from context import config
```

which works fine bcz I store config.py in local file system in context folder

But if i want this config.py file in memory instead of local file system

like

```
import { fs } from 'memfs';
fs.writeFileSync("/config.py", "script content");
```

Is there any way to do this because If I store file in local file system and import it its working fine. but i dont want that way because everytime i have to store these files(files to import) in localFS before executing main script.

Can somebody help me to get it done

Comment: I am sorry but this is a [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/397459). For a reason you do not want to explain, you are trying to store a Python file into a nodejs memfs file system, and later use that from inside a Python interpretor. As [memfs](https://github.com/streamich/memfs) documents neither its internal structure nor any API for a different language the only possibility to go that way would be to rewrite memfs in Python from the source itself. You should instead explain the context (running inside a browser or not, on a controlled client or not) ...

Comment: ... and the reason for switching from JavaScript to Python. The first step (using memfs to store a file in memory) is indeed easy, but the next one (using that memory buffer from Python) is probably harder than the real problem. Nothing is really bad in asking the question: if somebody had a compatible Python module, is could have been a piece of cake. But unfortunately you got no true answer after 3 questions on the same topic. So IMHO the best to do is to go one step back and look for a possible different way.